# javafx Menubar prevent alt or alt gr key

Tags: swing, javafx

I have a MenuBar with a few menus inside. In a Textfield I want to write {. So I use ALT GR and 8.
The effect is, the menubar is highlighted. This is not the expecteded behavior. Their is no solution on the web.

This is a windows system. But this should be the reason for this behavior. It should be possible to prevent the menubar for hihglighting and to write in textfield or textarea the special character.

Thank you.

I have found out, that this behavior is the same in a javafx textfield but the special char is printed! 
But in a swing SwingNode with a textarea this is never shown!

Comment: This is probably a bug, maybe this one: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8147821  

What version of JRE are you using? Some related bugs have been fixed in 8u60.

Comment: Hi, I am using 1.8.131